# Version of IBM Cloud pak for data

Tags: palantir-for-ibm-cloudpak-for-data

Could you please let me know how to check the current version of IBM Cloud pak for data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Select your Cloud Pak avatar from the top right, then select "About":

[image: Cloud Pak avatar]